# Form onSubmit doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I tried to use the onSubmit as a function, but this didn't really work out.
That's my form:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" onreset="resetFunction()" onsubmit="submitFunction()">
```

And this is my function:

```
 function submitFunction(){
    $('.hide').hide("fast");
    $('#email').updateStatus();
    $('#passwort').updateStatus();
    $('#passwordwd').updateStatus();
    $('#hobby').updateStatus();
    $('input[name=gender], input[name=sportart]').updateStatus();
    check=1;

}
```

The hide doesn't get executed.
It just clears all the fields and does nothing else.

Here's the updateStatus code:

```
function updateStatus() {
    var person = [];
    person[0] = $('#email').val();
    person[1] = $('#passwort').val();
    person[2] = $('#passwortwd').val();
    person[3] = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
    person[4] = $('input[name=sportart]:checked').val();
    person[5] = $('#hobby').val();


    $('#status').text(JSON.stringify(person));
}
```

Comment: probly the form is getting submited. If you want to change the behavior of the submit you should use event.preventDefault() inside this method.

Comment: What is `updateStatus`?

Comment: @Tushar It's a function, which I made. How can I use it, because it doesn't work this way?

Comment: Can you provide the updateStatus() function code too

Comment: @AdamJeffers see update

Comment: Why are you needing to do `$('#email').updateStatus()`? when you can just call the `updateStatus();`?

Comment: @ChrisBeckett Yes, and only once

Comment: @aha364636 Check my answer below

Comment: @aha364636 What is `#status`? Is that submitted to server?

Answer (score 2):

The submit function runs when you submit the form.

When you submit the form, you load a new page.

Any DOM changes made to the previous page will be lost.

You'll need to implement them with server side code for them to appear in the new page.

---

Additionally, `$('#email').updateStatus();` and co wouldn't do anything other than error and cause `submitFunction` to abort.

You've defined `function updateStatus()` as a global (which it is designed to be used as since it doesn't deal with context at all), not as [a jQuery plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

---

If you want to prevent the form from being submitted (in which case make sure [you have a sensible fallback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)) then you need to:

1. Fix the errors in the JS (call `updateStatus()` just once, and do it directly (not as a jQuery method).
2. Stop the form from submitting (by adding `return false` to the end of the `onSubmit` function). You would be better off moving to JavaScript bound events though. Intrinsic event attributes are rife with gotchas and fail to deal with [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Comment: You can also suggest to use `$('form').serialize();` instead of using the `person` array

Comment: @Tushar — That would give completely different results.

Comment: @Tushar — It would give completely different results either way, and if they were submitting to the server I would expect to see `val()` not `text()`.

Answer (score -1):

Change your submit function to:

```
function submitFunction(){
    $('.hide').hide("fast");
    $('#email').updateStatus();
    $('#passwort').updateStatus();
    $('#passwordwd').updateStatus();
    $('#hobby').updateStatus();
    $('input[name=gender], input[name=sportart]').updateStatus();
    check=1;
    return false;
}
```

By returning false in the onSubmit function, the page won't actually submit the form, so the page won't reload, so the DOM manipulations you make should stay on the screen.

Comment: Still will submit, user still would need to change the event handler. `onsubmit="return submitFunction()">`

Comment: "By returning false in the onSubmit function, the page won't actually submit the form" — That is true, but adding `return false` to the end of the `submitFunction` function won't cause the `onSubmit` function to return `false`. Stopping the form from submitting might not be desirable anyway, submitting is what forms are designed for.

Comment: add `return` before the `on submit` attr

Answer (score -1):

Use this form:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" onreset="resetFunction()" onsubmit="submitFunction(); return false;">
```

Or use this jQuery code:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    $('.hide').hide("fast");
    $('#email').updateStatus();
    $('#passwort').updateStatus();
    $('#passwordwd').updateStatus();
    $('#hobby').updateStatus();
    $('input[name=gender], input[name=sportart]').updateStatus();
    var check = 1;

    e.preventDefault();
});
```